# When do we say "earth" instead of "Earth"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if all of these can pretty much mean the same thing "earth" and "Earth" and "the earth" and "the Earth".

Because if earth means surface of the planet Earth, then it doesn't really matter what you decide to use and all sentences regardless of using a capitalized E or not will result in the same meaning, or a meaning that's synonymous to the point it virtually makes no difference.

Is there an exception though?

Here's an example:

> I believe the earth is flat, and you reach reach the edge of the earth
>   by swimming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just say

> I believe the earth is flat.

that is ambiguous, because **earth** also means dirt, or the ground, and this sentence could mean that you have prepared a vegetable garden for sowing and now it is flat, as far as you can tell. But if you say

> I believe the Earth is flat.

it is completely clear what you mean, and your assumption about the capitalisation not mattering is untrue.

Answer (score 0):

The capitol letter should be used when referring to the specific planet we are on.

> I believe the earth is flat.

Is a mistake, if referring to the whole world, as it probably is. it should always be

> I believe the Earth is flat.

The lower-case word  "earth" is used when referring to dirt or soil as in:

The builders used a million tons of earth to make the dam.

The lower-case word "earth" is also used when referring to generic planets more or less similar to this one.

> Many people  think that there are millions of earths, each one having developed life.
>
> The SF novel *Fire Time* is set on a distant earth.

The sentence

> I believe the earth is flat.

could only be correct if the intended meaning is something like

> I believe that the earth [at the building site] is flat.

Comment: One of the definitions is: The land surface of the world.

Comment: It is common to call our planet "the earth", in lower case. Whether or not you *approve* of this usage, it is certainly English usage.